# Write access violation occurring in C++ program

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to do a homework assignment that reads an integer in from C++ and passes it to a Python function that will display a multiplication table or double the integer. Note: the callIntFunc() function was given code by my instructor. I only wrote the code in main():

```
    int callIntFunc(string proc, int param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(i)", param);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;

    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}


void displayMenu() {
    cout << setfill('=') << setw(45) << " " << endl;
    cout << "1: Display a Multiplication Table" << endl;
    cout << "2: Double a Value" << endl;
    cout << "3: Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your selection as number 1, 2, or 3" << endl;
    cout << setfill('=') << setw(45) << " " << endl;
}



int main()
{

    
    
    int userInput;

    displayMenu();

    cin >> userInput;


    //While loop for input validation to check to see if anything other than 1, 2 or 3 is entered
    while (userInput != 1 && userInput != 2 && userInput != 3) {
        cout << "Invalid input, enter 1, 2 or 3" << endl;
        displayMenu();
        cin >> userInput;

    }
    //Creates a multiplication table with given number if user entered 1
    if (userInput == 1) {
        cout << "Enter a number to create a multiplication table" << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
        cout << callIntFunc("MultiplicationTable", userInput) << endl;
    }
    //Doubles the given number if user entered 2
    else if (userInput == 2) {
        cout << "Enter a number to double it" << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
        cout << callIntFunc("DoubleValue", userInput) << endl;
    }
    //Exits program if user entered 3
    else if (userInput == 3) {
        cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "\nDone\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The error occurs on the line with Py_DECREF(pValue). I also posted the call stack:

```
>   Integrating Languages.exe!callIntFunc(std::string proc, int param) Line 129 C++
Integrating Languages.exe!main() Line 190   C++
[External Code] 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]


import re
import string


def printsomething():
    print("Hello from python!")

def PrintMe(v):
    print("You sent me: " + v)
    return 100;

def SquareValue(v):
    return v * v


def MultiplicationTable(num): 
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(str(num) + "x " + str(i) + "= " + str(num * i))  
    return -1       

def DoubleValue(num):
    return num * 2
```

Comment: Do you see how `Py_DECREF` might be passed `nullptr`?

Comment: @DrewDormann I see that pValue is initialized as a nullptr. Being new to C++, i'm not sure what to do about it. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: The lack of error handling in the function you were given is baffling. Giving that to students and expecting them to figure out what could have gone wrong is even more baffling.

Comment: @camzfl without going into a deep lesson on how `if`/`else` works, you have written a functiion that might enter your `else` branch, in which case `pValue` is still `nullptr` and `Py_DECREF(pValue);` should absolutely not be executed.

Comment: @camzfl *NOTE: the callIntFunc() function was given code by my instructor.* -- I vaguely remember the same or similar code in a question a few months ago.  As I recall, after the error checking was actually done, it was determined that the value(s) were indeed `nullptr`.  I think your teacher needs a few lessons in writing code that actually checks for errors.

Comment: @camzfl And bingo, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263820/c6011-in-c-and-python-project).

Comment: @DrewDormann Sorry, but can you explain further? I think the function you're referring to is callIntFunc(). Just to clarify, I did not write that code and i'm not sure how to fix it if that is the problem.

Comment: @camzfl -- See the link in the previous comment.  The code is poorly written in terms of checking for errors.  Which goes to show that the state of affairs when it comes to teachers providing code is going downhill in terms of quality.

Comment: Since you have not written `callIntFunc`, this is probably the time to approach your instructor and ask the question in the very first comment here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I'm trying to understand the steps the code is taking by reading the python docs. To my understanding, the PyCallable_Check() function is returning 0 instead of 1 and causing it to skip the if statement. But I don't understand why or how to fix it? Do you mind pointing me in the correct direction?

Comment: Did you read the issues at the link in the comment I gave?  Is `pDict` a `nullptr`?  Note -- I am no expert in python, so I can't help you there.  However, my experience is with C++, and if an API, regardless if it's python-related or not, when the docs tell you that a `null` can be returned, then you must check for this return value -- you can't simply assume all of those calls will be successful.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah, I have attempted help from my instructor, he seems to think this problem is being caused due to the specific drives/locations and where visual studio is creating them, but if that were true I don't think any of the functions would work correctly, including the ones that were given by the instructor

Comment: So basically, your instructor is saying "it works on my machine".  The code obviously does not check for errors, when the documentation clearly states that these functions will return `nullptr` or something to indicate an error has occurred.

Comment: We can not control what your instructor says, but it remains that your instructor has given you buggy code.  Feel free to send your instructor this post, so they may read the comments.

Comment: The code seems to be some stock code given to students in various courses and semesters, and no instructor has taken the time to actually fix it or enhance the error reporting (when clearly it should be).  The link in my comment indicates this is the case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I apologize for all the questions but I'm still new to C++. How would I  check for a return value for pDict?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah and the same code needs to be used for the final project, so if I don't fix it then i'm going to continue having problems

Comment: @camzfl -- It has nothing to do really with C++, and everything to do with [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html).  Look at `PyModule_GetDict` and read the docs carefully.  What does it say about returning `NULL` if something is wrong?  So if `pDict` is null after calling that function, you have a reference to give to the teacher as to the probable reason why it is occurring.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I appreciate you taking the time and helping. I'll work at it and get in touch with my instructor so hopefully nobody else has to go through this

Comment: @camzfl For me your C++ and Python code fully works. I pasted your Python code into file `PythonCode.py` and copied your C++ code and compiled it too. Both work. Selecting in menu DoubleValue works and also Multiplication Table works. Do you have anything yet unfixed that I need to look at?